# Cirq seems to output 0 instead of |2> with qutrits

Tags: cirq, quantum-state

I am experimenting a bit with qutrits on Cirq and came across a problem: my output is 0 when it should be |2>.

I defined my qutrit as follows:

```
qutrit = cirq.NamedQid('qtr', dimension=3)
```

And defined the following 'NOT' gates:

- This NOT gate takes my |0> and 'flips' it to |1>

```
    class qutrit_01(cirq.Gate): 
        def _qid_shape_(self):      
            return (3,)
        def _unitary_(self):
            return np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                             [1, 0, 0],
                             [0, 0, 1]])
        def _circuit_diagram_info_(self, args):
            return "X"
```

This works nicely when added to a circuit. However, the following 2 NOT gates do not work as expected:

- This NOT gate takes my |1> and (should) 'flip' it to |2>

```
class qutrit_12(cirq.Gate): 
    def _qid_shape_(self):      
        return (3,)
    def _unitary_(self):
        return np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                         [0, 0, 1],
                         [0, 1, 0]])
    def _circuit_diagram_info_(self, args):
        return "XX"
```

- This NOT gate takes my |0> and (should) 'flip' it to |2>:

```
class qutrit_02(cirq.Gate): 
    def _qid_shape_(self):      
        return (3,)
    def _unitary_(self):
        return np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                         [0, 1, 0],
                         [1, 0, 0]])
    def _circuit_diagram_info_(self, args):
        return "XXX"
```

I then add the gates to a circuit as follows:

```
NOT01 = qutrit_01()
NOT12 = qutrit_12()
NOT02 = qutrit_02()

circuit = cirq.Circuit()
circuit.append(NOT01.on(qutrit))
circuit.append(NOT12.on(qutrit))
s = cirq.Simulator()
results = s.simulate(circuit)
print(results)
```

As usual, the qutrit is automatically initialised in the |0> state. When I use the NOT01 gate, I get as expected |1> as output vector. However, when I then also add the NOT12 gate I get 0 as output vector (just the value, not even as a ket). Similarly, if I only add the NOT02 gate I get 0 as output vector. So, it seems like it outputs 0 when it should output |2>. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [This has been fixed](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/6180). You can get it by installing the latest `dev` version of Cirq with the command  `pip install cirq==1.2.0.dev20230704233149`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cirq should be outputting |2⟩ instead of 0 but it's not. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/6165).

It is indeed simulating qutrits which you can confirm with

```
print(cirq.qid_shape(results))
# prints
# (3,)
```

Measuring the circuit and sampling will destroy the statevector but it does print the correct result

```
circuit.append(cirq.measure(qutrit))
result = cirq.sample(circuit)
# prints
# qtr (d=3)=2
```